# Многократный вызов функции декоратора

Tags: javascript

написал простую функцию декоратор для вывода в консоль функции факториала, но вместо одного результата , выводится несколько, почему так подскажите пожалуйста?

```
     let fac = function (n) {
  return n!=1 ? n * fac(n - 1) : 1;
}

function logfactorial( func) {
  return function () {
    let result = func.call(this, ...arguments);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}

fac = logfactorial(fac);

fac(6);
```

вывод в консоль:
1
2
6
24
120
720

Comment: потому что функция рекурсивная и внутри себя вызывает себя же.

Answer (score 1):

Функция рекурсивная и внутри себя вызывает себя же с помощью замыкания переменной `fac`. При создании декоратора ты заменяешь эту переменную и в замыкании теперь не просто функция, а уже задекорированная, которая на каждый вызов выводит лог.

Если лог должен быть один - замыкать нужно не локальную переменну.

Например можно замкнуть саму функцию, если дать ей имя

```
function fac(n) {
  return n != 1 ? n * fac(n - 1) : 1;
}
```

В этом случае внутри функции будет использована сама функция, а не внешняя переменная.

Пример:

```js
let fac = function fac(n) {
  return n != 1 ? n * fac(n - 1) : 1;
}

function logfactorial(func) {
  return function() {
    let result = func.call(this, ...arguments);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}

fac = logfactorial(fac);

fac(6);
```

Comment: премного благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Это не декораторы, а обычные замыкания. Возможно, стоит сменить обучающие материалы, тк сейчас декораторами называют совершенно другое:

```js
function log(...args) {
  console.log(args)
}

@log
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  } 
}
```

Данный синтаксис пока не поддерживается нативно, но уже работает в транспиляторах яваскрипт.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

А что касается факториала:

```js
function fac(n) { for (let i=r=1; i<=n; i++) r*=i; return r }
```

Для его вычисления не нужны рекурсия и замыкания,  но если хочется, то:

```js
function fac(n) {
  let i = 1, r = 1
  return () => (i <= n) ? (r *= i++) : r 
}
c = fac(5)
c()
1
c()
2
c()
6
c()
24
c()
120
```